# VBA Excel 2003 Printing pages in custom order

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, excel-2003, vba

I have an excel (2003) workbook. I need to print a booklet of certain information contain in the workbook.

Is it possible to print one page from one worksheet then another page from another worksheet in **one** print job as the print setup is as a booklet? I have been searching the internet for some time without any luck.

One possibilty I have come across in my search is saving each worksheet to a pdf file so the pdf file will contain 10 pages. The only issue with this is adding a 3rd party dll as my company has strict rules on this. If there is a built in method that does this please let me know as I can't find it.

Thanks,
M

Comment: Have you tried moving your sheets into the order you want them to be printed in then printing the entire workbook?

Comment: No I haven't tried that as there are only certain sheets I would like to print. Is there a way to print a workbook but exclude certain sheets?

Comment: Yes, you can "group" the sheets you want to print by pressing [CTRL] while selecting the sheet tabs you want to print then printing. Be sure to "ungroup" the sheets after printing by right-clicking any sheet tab and clicking "Ungroup" from the drop-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in an array

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet3", "Sheet1")).PrintOut
```